# Comparar el valor de una Consulta en Linq

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, linq

Hola buen día gente estoy trabajando en asp.net mvc EF tengo la siguiente consulta en linq

```
var fabricador = from f in db.Eq_tblFabricante
                                       where f.id == eq_TblSoftware.Eq_tblFabricante_id
                                       select f.Fabricante;
```

quisiera hacer una comparación para la toma de decisión algo como

```
if(fabricador == "FABRICA X"){
//código
}
```

pero no me permite ninguna de las dos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bienvenido a la comunidad!

La variable "fabricador" contiene el resultado de la consulta, es decir es una lista; en lugar de el resultado de una consulta, puedes utilizar el método "First" para que te devuelva no una lista, sino un solo objeto de tu clase (el primero que aparezca).

```
var fabricador = db.Eq_tblFabricante.First(f=> f.Id == elValorQueBuscas);
if(fabricador.Fabricante=="FABRICA X"){
  //codigo
}
```

También puedes probar con la función FirstOrDefault()

Avísame si te funciona.

(Ten muy en cuenta el uso de minúsculas o mayúsculas, por ejemplo en **f.Id** lo escribí con mayúscula, pero debe estar escrito dependiendo de como está tu Clase creada)

Comment: Hola Hugo Quiñonez en efecto se debía usar el operador first ya que como dices la consulta me trae una lista al final quedo asi 
            var fabricador = (from f in db.Eq_tblFabricante
                              where f.id == eq_TblSoftware.Eq_tblFabricante_id
                              select f.Fabricante).First();                                                                        gracias por tu ayuda marcare tu respuesta como correcta

Comment: @Oscar. Ten cuidado. `First()` va a tirar una excepción en caso que ningún elemento de la colección cumpla con la condición. Úsalo únicamente si estás **absolutamente** seguro que **siempre** habrá al menos un registro devuelto, y que es un caso excepcional si no lo hay. Si no es así, o no estás seguro, utiliza `FirstOrDefault`, y luego evalúa el objeto para ver si viene null.

Comment: Arriel muchas gracias por el Consejo lo aplicare inmediatamente